# Filter array with specified conditions

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have a big array like this:

```
[
"id" : "100",
"uuid": "7594873",
"parameters" => [
    "type" => "fast",
    "height" => "140"]
],[
"id" : "101"
"uuid": "7594872"
"parameters" => [
    "type" => "slow",
    "height" => "140"]
],[
"id" : "102",
"uuid": "7594875",
"parameters" => [
    "type" => "fast",
    "height" => "120"]
],[
"id" : "114",
"uuid": "7294876",
"parameters" => [
    "type" => "fast",
    "height" => "125",]
],[
"id" : "115",
"uuid": "7294123",
"parameters" => [
    "type" => "fast",
    "height" => "120",
    ]
]
```

I would like to return (in PHP 7) specified result with condition the same type parameter as parent and specified height that equals "120".

In this example array result should be:

["7594873" => ["7594875", "7294123"]]

Should I use array_filter? I have 100 000 records in array and I want to search as fast as possible.

Comment: How do you know which records are parents and which are children?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you would use `var_export` to output your sample data; then it can be read directly as PHP for testing purposes.

Comment: foreach is faster then array_filter because array_filter is using closure function.

Comment: so maybe array_search with array_column?

Comment: This question should be closed as Unclear because we do not have a clear problem statement or [mcve]. We don't know what "parent" refers to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution with a simple foreach which creates a new array:

```
$type = $arr[0]['parameters']['type']; //or what is parent type ?

$result = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $row){
  if($row['parameters']['type'] != $type) continue;
  if($row['parameters']['height'] != 120) continue;
  if($row['id'] <= 100) continue;
  $result[$key] = $row;
}
```

With continue the remainder of the current loop iteration is skipped in loop structures and the execution then continues with the next iteration.

Result:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => "102",
    'uuid' => "7594875",
    'parameters' => 
    array (
      'type' => "fast",
      'height' => "120",
    ),
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => "115",
    'uuid' => "7294123",
    'parameters' => 
    array (
      'type' => "fast",
      'height' => "120",
    ),
  ),
)
```